# Why is the pointer value in the function different to the one passed in as an argument?

Tags: c++, pass-by-value

I have the following constructor:

```
MutexWrapper::MutexWrapper(Mutex * pMutex)
{
  DebugPrint("0x%x", pMutex); // displays 0x1f83e54
}
```

And it gets called in the following function:

```
void OnReviewBuffer_Callback( void * pUserData )
{
  ReviewBuffer * thePointer = (ReviewBuffer *) pUserData;

  DebugPrint("0x%x", thePointer); // this displays 0x1f83e48

  MutexWrapper theMutexWrapper(thePointer);
}
```

Unfortunately I can't provide the entire definition of `ReviewBuffer` - but I hope the below is enough:

```
class ReviewBuffer  : public StreamConsumer_Base, public Mutex
{
  ...
};
```

The problem is that when I print out `thePointer` I get `0x1f83e48`, but the value printed from inside the constructor is `0x1f83e54`.

Why are the pointer values different - is this something to do with pass by value passing in a copy of the pointer?

Comment: @John Dibling, I removed IN from the question - it's #define'd to expand to nothing ( it's purely for reader's benefit ).

Comment: chris yes that's exactly what it is for.

Comment: @BeeBand Are you sure that `DebugPrint("0x%x", thePointer);` just  before the declaration of `theMutexWrapper` gives a different value?

Comment: Is `thePointer` also `Mutex*`? Are you printing it in exactly the same way, just before creating the wrapper?

Comment: Please show us the code that prints the pointer before the call, as well as the exact definition of this pointer. I suspect this is an inheritance/polymorphism issue.

Comment: @syam - i have edited post, i hope this is clearer.

Comment: @BeeBand: yes. This goes the way I suspect. Could you also give us the class declaration for `ReviewBuffer` to confirm it?

Comment: @syam - I have added as much as I can.

Comment: @BeeBand: yes this is enough, it's indeed what I thought. I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class `ReviewBuffer` uses multiple inheritance:

```
class ReviewBuffer  : public StreamConsumer_Base, public Mutex
{
  ...
};
```

The internal layout of the class (probably*) looks like this:

```
Offset 0    class StreamConsumer_Base
            ... contents of that class (12 bytes including alignment: 0x1f83e54 - 0x1f83e48)
Offset 12   class Mutex
            ... contents of that class (unknown size)
```

(*) *probably* because nothing in the standard mandates this. This is just the usual way compilers implement it.

When you initially print `thePointer`, it points to the `ReviewBuffer` object ie. offset 0 of the class. But when you pass it to your function, the pointer automatically gets adjusted by the compiler to point to the `Mutex` part of `ReviewBuffer`. Since that `Mutex` part is at offset 12, the value of the pointer cannot be the same (think about it: if it was the same, it would not point to a `Mutex` but to either a `ReviewBuffer` or a `StreamConsumer_Base`).

Answer (score 2):

Your non-default constructor `MutexWrapper::MutexWrapper` takes a `Mutex*` pointer as an argument. Your function `OnReviewBuffer_Callback` casts the provided `void*` pointer to a `ReviewBuffer*` pointer. The only way you can pass that `ReviewBuffer*` pointer as an argument to `MutexWrapper::MutexWrapper(Mutex*)` is if `ReviewBuffer` is a derived class of `Mutex`. If `ReviewBuffer` also inherits from other classes, downcasting a `ReviewBuffer*` pointer to a `Mutex*` pointer may result in a pointer with a different address than the original. That is exactly what's going on, based on the latest edit. `ReviewBuffer` uses multiple inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

In C++ as in Java, pointer are passed by value. 
Pass-by-reference is a misnomer.

Of course, pointer pointing to the same **address** variable, it looks like the whole is passed-by-reference, but...isn't.

Comment: "Pass-by-reference is a misnomer [in C++]"  **Defend this statement**.

Comment: There are no references here. The pointer is passed by value but (apparently) has a different value in the function. (And I've no idea what you mean by a "misnomer"; pass-by-reference is well defined in C++, it's just not happening here).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426474/is-passing-pointer-argument-pass-by-value-in-c

Comment: This would only hold if the debug print printed the address of the pointer, but it looks like it should be printing the value of the pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Yes I interpreted differently the question, you're right.

Comment: @JohnDibling Well I'm somebody who absolutely avoids saying "pass by reference" when passing a pointer by value. The terminology has come over from C and is just confusing when applied to C++, particularly because we actually have reference types. The `Mutex` isn't being passed by reference; it's not being passed at all. In fact, the pointer that is passed (by value) needn't even be pointing at a `Mutex` object. This is only really a criticism of how the question is tagged though, and this answer doesn't really apply to the question itself.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Passing a pointer by-value, as is done in the OP, is not passing by-reference.

Comment: @JohnDibling The question is tagged [tag:pass-by-reference], though, as though the asker thinks passing a pointer is passing by reference (which *is* what C programmers say). This is what Mik378 is referring to in his answer by saying "pass-by-reference is a misnomer".

Comment: @sftrabbit - no, I just couldn't find the pass-by-value tag - i have changed it.

Comment: @Mik378: Your link does not defend an assertion that there is no pass-by-reference in C++.  Please elaborate what you mean, exactly, when you say that "Pass-by-reference is a misnomer [in C++]"

Comment: @sftrabbit: I see.  I hadn't noticed that tag on the question before you pointed it out.  Mik378, is this what you're referring to?  Or are you really saying there is no pass-by-reference in C++?

Comment: @John Dibling First, maybe and surely I merely misread (too quickly?) the question, as I said in one comment just above. I expected the user wanted to assert that the address of the original pointer still remains  unchanged after passing it by method argument. Thus, in this typical interpretation, I wanted to inform that passing a pointer doesn't mean that the pointer itself is not passed by value. In this case, someone would pass the address of the pointer (as shown in the 0x499602D2's answer). Sorry for this wrong interpretation by the way.