# I lose pointer or an address? It acts like never happen

Tags: c++, function-pointers

So the problem is I have a function for example

```
int * fun2(){...}

int fun(int *a)
{
   a = fun2(); // this is like line never exist
}
```

I want to assign returned pointer by fun2 to pointer a and it doesnt happen WHY?

And an "a" variable has already a value, before assigning fun2(), but I dont think so it really matter.

Comment: How are you testing whether or not it happens?

Comment: If you are asking "why does `a` still have the old value after I call `fun(a)`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426474/is-passing-pointer-argument-pass-by-value-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a` is a temporary object in `fun()`. I fyou want `fun()` to change the pointer to `a` you'll need to take the pointer as reference:

```
int fun(int*& a) {
    a = fun2();
}
```

Note that this interface is probably severely broken.

Answer (score 1):

It does work. It changes the value of `a` in the local scope.

If you want to see change outside of `fun`, you have to pass a reference: `int fun(int *&a)`.

(Note: you *have to* provide us a complete example which demonstrates your problem, so we don't have to do educated *guesses*).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to pass the address of the `a` pointer variable:

```
int fun(int **a)
{
  *a = func2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed the pointer by value. Inside the function, it's a new copy of that pointer. You change only the copy in there.