# need to write a function that takes a string an integer offset and size and prints starting from offset and upto offset+size the string

Tags: c, pointers

the idea is to trim the string starting from the value of offset and upto the value of size and return along with the new string return 1; and if it gets outside of code boundery to simply return 0 .
This is my code:

```
int subPrint(char *s, int offset,int size){
    char *m;
    m = (s + offset);
    while(size != 0){
     m = (m + 1);
    if(m == '\0')
        return 0;
    size--;

 }
 s = m;
return 1;

}

void subPrintTest(){
     char s[20] = "INDUSTRIAL";
     subPrint(s,2,4);
     printf("%s",s);
 }

void main(){
     subPrintTest();
     getch();
 }
```

The problem is that its printing the original string s unchanged

Comment: I don't see the problem, *why* should the original string change or be modified in any way? Does the program work as it should otherwise? Or maybe you should change your `subPrint` function to actually *print* something? Otherwise it's badly named.

Comment: I dont need to print it using subPrint but using subPrintTest and it doesnt need to print it all only the part I specified

Comment: So you want your function to *get* a substring and not print it? Then you need a destination to copy it to.

Comment: that why I created the new pointer m and stored what I needed in it but even though there is something missing

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the pointer s is being passed by value to the function subPrint. In order to do what you intend, you could pass a pointer to the pointer s.

Reference: [Is passing pointer argument, pass by value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426474/is-passing-pointer-argument-pass-by-value-in-c)

Comment: Yes. You could pass &s to the function subPrint. Inside subPrint use *s =m;

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the code you have and replace this line `s = m` with `memcpy(destination, src, size_t)`  You will need to include string.h

Comment: the problem is I am not allowed to use string.h library or else it would be rather easier

Comment: Better to use `memove()` than `memcpy()`.  `memcpy()` is not well defined for arrays that overlap, `memove()` is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

OP's `subPrint(char *s, int offset,int size)` changes some variables in the code but never affects the array pointed to by `s` nor prints anything.

---

`subPrint()` not needed.  Use `"%.*s"` to specify the *precision* field and limit the width of the output.

```
char s[20] = "INDUSTRIAL";
int offset = 2;
assert(offset >= 0 && offset <= strlen(s));
int size = 4;
printf("%.*s", 4, s + 2);
```

---

Or simply

```
int subPrintA(char *s, int offset,int size) {
  while (offset > 0 && *s) {
    offset--;
    s++;
  }
  while (size > 0 && *s) {
    putchar(*s);
    size--;
    s++;
  }
}
```

Comment: can`t use strlen as it is not allowed by the exercise I am solving

Comment: @AliHaroon Rather than put limitations like can't [use strlen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535031/need-to-write-a-function-that-takes-a-string-an-integer-offset-and-size-and-prin/40536358#comment68312491_40536358) in  a comment, well after posting, kinder to include that restriction in the original post.  IAC, `strlen()` used here is an error check - non-essential to the code.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning this before and thx for the suggestion anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are manipulating the string pointers else where and expect the original string to be affected. Do the printing in `subPrint` and you should get the desired result.

```
int subPrint(char *s, int offset,int size) {
    char *m;
    m = (s + offset);
    while(size != 0){
     if(*m == '\0')
        return 0;
     putchar(*m); // printing is done here
     m = (m + 1);
     size--;
    }
    return 1;
}

void subPrintTest(){
     char s[20] = "INDUSTRIAL";
     subPrint(s,2,4);
}
```

Comment: The will `putchar('\0');`,if `offset == strlen(s)` - of course, size should be <= 0 in that case.  `if(m == '\0')` is odd.  Perhaps `if(*m == '\0')`?

Comment: well thx this seems to sove the issue with printing the string @smac89