# Why does not the value of the pointer passed to the function change?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I pass the pointer as a parameter to the function. Inside the function I change it -> it has changed. But after the output is the same as before the function call. The pointer has not changed. What's wrong?

```
void GetFrom(PVOID lpBuffer){
lpBuffer = malloc(12);
memset(lpBuffer, 0, 12);
printf("%p",pointer); // 0000028D46DECE50
}

PVOID pointer = 0x0;
printf("%p",pointer); // 000000C2628FEFE4
GetFromMap(pointer);
printf("%p",pointer); // 000000C2628FEFE4
```

In debugging, I saw that the value of the pointer changed inside the function.

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4426487/6610379

Answer (score 1):

Note that `lpBuffer = malloc(12)` just changes the value of local variable `lpBuffer`, but this has no effect to the variable which's value has been passed to `GetFrom`. To change the value of the pointer in the caller`s variable, you need to pass a pointer to that pointer.

```
void GetFrom(PVOID *lpBuffer){
  *lpBuffer = malloc(12);
  memset(*lpBuffer, 0, 12);
  printf("%p",*lpBuffer); // !=0x0
}

PVOID pointer = 0x0;
GetFromMap(&pointer);
printf("%p",pointer); // should be != 0x0
```

BTW: instead of `malloc` and a subsequent `memset to 0`, you could use `calloc`, which implicitly fills the allocated memory with `0`-

Answer (score 0):

> Inside the function I change it -> it has changed.

Not exactly: the "it" that has changed is the *copy* of the pointer, not the original pointer that has been passed.

> But after the output is the same as before the function call. The pointer has not changed.

That's because you changed a copy, while the pointer retained its original value.

As far as fixing this situation goes, you have one option in C and two options in C++:

- In C, pass a pointer to a pointer. This will let your function make changes to the pointer passed into it
- In C++, you can also pass a reference to a pointer. This will produce the same behavior without the need to use dereference operator explicitly.