# Pointer to beginning of linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

I am practicing linked list structure while learning pointers and I have problem with appending item in list. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node node_t;
struct node {
    int data;
    node_t* next;
};

void append(node_t *head, int data) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        node_t *node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
        node->data = data;
        node->next = NULL;
        head = node;
    } else {
        node_t *node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
        node->data = data;
        node->next = NULL;

        if (head->next == NULL) {
            head->next = node;
        } else {
            node_t *current = head;
            while (1) {
                if (current->next == NULL) {
                    current->next = node;
                    break;
                }
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    node_t *head = NULL;

    append(head, 4);
    append(head, 6);
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

My code breaks when I do `head = node;` It doesn't change value of `head` in `main`. I think I'm missing something but not sure what. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Remember that in C arguments to functions are *passed by value*. This means the value is *copied* into the argument variable. Modifying the argument variable (being a copy) does not modify the original value. Please do some research about *emulating pass by value in C*.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the pointer head by value in the function append. So the function deals with a copy of the passed to it pointer. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer. Either pass it by reference or return updated head from the function.

The first approach is much better.

The function can look the following way

```
int append( node_t **head, int data )
{
    node_t *node = malloc( sizeof( node_t ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node node_t;
struct node
{
    int data;
    node_t *next;
};

int append( node_t **head, int data )
{
    node_t *node = malloc( sizeof( node_t ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}

void printList( node_t *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    node_t *head = NULL;

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        append( &head, i );
    }

    printList( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is you are passing the `head` pointer **by value**, so when you change it inside `append()`, you're only changing a local variable in that function - as opposed to the `head` variable within `main()`.

This may be a bit confusing - if you pass a pointer, how can you be passing by value? Well, you might want to have a look at this question:

[Is passing pointer argument, pass by value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4426474/1593077)

... and the bottom line is that `append()` needs to take a `node_t** head`, and you'll call it from main with `append(&head, 4);`. See it [working on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78096fbc6eb27811).

Also you're allocating `sizeof(node_t*)` per node. You should be allocating `sizeof(node_t)`.

Comment: if i make it global it still doesnt change it but it should right?

Comment: @lukaa123 If you make `head` a global variable, then it depends on whether or not it is 'hidden' by another local variable with the same name. Also, you shouldn't use global variables - it's bad practice that leads to bugs and headaches with larger programs.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the head of the list by value, so the `append` function cannot update the pointer in the caller's space, that happens to have the same name `head`. The `head` argument in `append` is a separate variable from the `head` local variable in `main`.

You should either pass a pointer to the head node so `append` can modify it:

```
void append(node_t **headp, int data) { ...
```

Or return the possibly modified head node to the caller which will store it back to its own variable:

```
node_t *append(node_t *head, int data) { ...
```

In both cases, it is advisable to signal memory allocation failure to the caller. Returning an error code in the first approach is easy, while returning a null pointer in the second approach can work, as long as the caller does not store the return value directly into its `head` variable, as in case of failure the previous value would be lost.

Here is a modified version with the first approach:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node node_t;
struct node {
    int data;
    node_t *next;
};

// append a new node to the list, return 0 for success, -1 for allocation failure
int append(node_t **headp, int data) {
    node_t *node = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t *));
    if (node == NULL)
        return -1;
    node->data = data;
    node->next = NULL;
    if (*headp == NULL) {
        *headp = node;
    } else {
        node_t *current = *headp;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = node;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    node_t *head = NULL;

    if (append(&head, 4) || append(&head, 6))
        printf("node allocation error\n");
    printList(head);
    // should free the list
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It doesn't change value of head in main

Nor should it! If the value of `head` in main changed when you call `append()`, then your call to `printList()` would only print the last node in the list, and you'd have no way to refer to the other nodes in the list.

The *reason* that `head` isn't changed has been well explained in other answers, i.e. you're passing the head pointer by value. It's important to understand that the `head` in `main()` and the `head` parameter in `append()` are entirely different variables.